# how to create new column 'count' in Spark DataFrame under some condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a DataFrame about connection log with columns `Id`, `targetIP`, `Time`. Every record in this DataFrame is a connection event to one system. Id means this connection, `targetIP` means the target IP address this time, Time is the connection time. With Values:

| ID | Time | targetIP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 2 | 2 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 3 | 3 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 4 | 5 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 5 | 6 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 6 | 7 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 7 | 8 | 192.163.0.2 |

I want to create a new column under some condition: count of connections to this time's target IP address in the past 2 time units. So the result DataFrame should be:

| ID | Time | targetIP | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 192.163.0.1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 192.163.0.2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 192.163.0.1 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 192.163.0.1 | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | 192.163.0.2 | 0 |
| 6 | 7 | 192.163.0.2 | 1 |
| 7 | 8 | 192.163.0.2 | 2 |

For example, `ID=7`, the `targetIP` is `192.163.0.2` Connected to system in past 2 time units, which are `ID=5` and `ID=6`, and their `targetIP` are also `192.163.0.2`. So the count about `ID=7` is 2.

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` over Window bounded with range between - 2 and current row, to get the count of IP in the last 2 time units.

Using Spark SQL you can do something like this:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("connection_logs")

df1 = spark.sql("""
    SELECT  *,
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY targetIP ORDER BY Time 
                          RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                          ) -1 AS count
    FROM    connection_logs
    ORDER BY ID
""")

df1.show()

#+---+----+-----------+-----+
#| ID|Time|   targetIP|count|
#+---+----+-----------+-----+
#|  1|   1|192.163.0.1|    0|
#|  2|   2|192.163.0.2|    0|
#|  3|   3|192.163.0.1|    1|
#|  4|   5|192.163.0.1|    1|
#|  5|   6|192.163.0.2|    0|
#|  6|   7|192.163.0.2|    1|
#|  7|   8|192.163.0.2|    2|
#+---+----+-----------+-----+
```

Or using DataFrame API:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

time_unit = lambda x: x

w = Window.partitionBy("targetIP").orderBy(col("Time").cast("int")).rangeBetween(-time_unit(2), 0)

df1 = df.withColumn("count", F.count("*").over(w) - 1).orderBy("ID")

df1.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

So, what you basically need is a window function.

Let's start with your initial data

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

case class Event(ID: Int, Time: Int, targetIP: String)

val events = Seq(
    Event(1, 1, "192.163.0.1"),
    Event(2, 2, "192.163.0.2"),
    Event(3, 3, "192.163.0.1"),
    Event(4, 5, "192.163.0.1"),
    Event(5, 6, "192.163.0.2"),
    Event(6, 7, "192.163.0.2"),
    Event(7, 8, "192.163.0.2")
).toDS()
```

Now we need to define a window function itself

```
val timeWindow = Window.orderBy($"Time").rowsBetween(-2, -1)
```

And now the most interesting part: how to count something over the window? There is no simple way, so we'll do the following

1. Aggregate all the targetIp's into the list
2. Filter the list to find only needed ips
3. Count size of the list

```
val df = events
        .withColumn("tmp", collect_list($"targetIp").over(timeWindow))
        .withColumn("count", size(expr("filter(tst, x -> x == targetIp)")))
        .drop($"tmp")
```

And the result will contain a new column "count" which we need!

UPD:

There is the much shorter version without aggregation, written by @blackbishop,

```
val timeWindow = Window.partitionBy($"targetIP").orderBy($"Time").rangeBetween(-2, Window.currentRow)
val df = events
        .withColumn("count", count("*").over(timeWindow) - lit(1))
        .explain(true)
```

Comment: Note that you should be using `rangeBetween` not `rowsBetween`. What if you add a row to the dataframe say `(8, 11, 192.163.0.2`)? Your solution will give `count=2`, it should be 0 as at time unit 11 -2 there were no connections.