# create a new column in spark dataframe under condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Another question! Similar is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66168969/how-to-create-new-column-count-in-spark-dataframe-under-some-condition)

I have a DataFrame about connection log with columns `ID`, `targetIP`,`targetPort`, `Time`. Every record in this DataFrame is a connection event to one system. `ID` means this connection, `targetIP` means the target IP address this time, `targetPort` means the target port,`Time` is the connection time. With Values:

| ID | Time | targetIP | targetPort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 192.163.0.1 | 53 |
| 2 | 2 | 192.163.0.2 | 54 |
| 3 | 3 | 192.163.0.1 | 1028 |
| 4 | 5 | 192.163.0.1 | 1028 |
| 5 | 6 | 192.163.0.2 | 63 |
| 6 | 7 | 192.163.0.2 | 64 |
| 7 | 8 | 192.163.0.2 | 63 |

I want to create a new column under condition: the percentage of connections that were to the same targetPort among the connections to current row's targetIP address in the past 2 time units. So the result DataFrame should be:

| ID | Time | targetIP | targetPort | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 192.163.0.1 | 53 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 192.163.0.2 | 54 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 192.163.0.1 | 1028 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 192.163.0.1 | 1028 | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | 192.163.0.2 | 63 | 0 |
| 6 | 7 | 192.163.0.2 | 64 | 0 |
| 7 | 8 | 192.163.0.2 | 63 | 0.5 |

For example, `ID=7`, the `targetIP` is `192.163.0.2`, `targetPort` is 63 .Connected to system in past 2 time units, which are `ID=5` and `ID=6`, and their `targetIP` are also `192.163.0.2` and only `ID=6` has the same targetPort as `ID=7`,which is 63. So the result about `ID=7` is 1/2 = 0.5 (also 50%).

python solution is best, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 windows, one partitioned by `targetIP` and `targetPort` and another by  only `targetIP`, then divide count over `w1` by count over `w2` to get the percentage in the last 2 time unit :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


w = Window.partitionBy("targetIP", "targetPort").orderBy(F.col("Time")).rangeBetween(-2, -1)
w2 = Window.partitionBy("targetIP").orderBy(col("Time")).rangeBetween(-2, -1)

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "result",
    F.coalesce(F.count("*").over(w) / F.count("*").over(w2), F.lit(0))
).orderBy("ID")

df1.show()

#+---+----+-----------+----------+------+
#| ID|Time|   targetIP|targetPort|result|
#+---+----+-----------+----------+------+
#|  1|   1|192.163.0.1|        53|   0.0|
#|  2|   2|192.163.0.2|        54|   0.0|
#|  3|   3|192.163.0.1|      1028|   0.0|
#|  4|   5|192.163.0.1|      1028|   1.0|
#|  5|   6|192.163.0.2|        63|   0.0|
#|  6|   7|192.163.0.2|        64|   0.0|
#|  7|   8|192.163.0.2|        63|   0.5|
#+---+----+-----------+----------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add two columns of ip_count and port_count using window functions, and divide them to get the ratio:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = df.withColumn(
    'ip_count', 
    F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('targetIP').orderBy('Time').rangeBetween(-2,-1))
).withColumn(
    'port_count',
    F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('targetIP', 'targetPort').orderBy('Time').rangeBetween(-2,-1))
).withColumn(
    'result',
    F.when(F.col('ip_count') != 0, F.col('port_count') / F.col('ip_count')).otherwise(0)
).orderBy('ID')

result.show()
+---+----+-----------+----------+--------+----------+------+
| ID|Time|   targetIP|targetPort|ip_count|port_count|result|
+---+----+-----------+----------+--------+----------+------+
|  1|   1|192.163.0.1|        53|       0|         0|   0.0|
|  2|   2|192.163.0.2|        54|       0|         0|   0.0|
|  3|   3|192.163.0.1|      1028|       1|         0|   0.0|
|  4|   5|192.163.0.1|      1028|       1|         1|   1.0|
|  5|   6|192.163.0.2|        63|       0|         0|   0.0|
|  6|   7|192.163.0.2|        64|       1|         0|   0.0|
|  7|   8|192.163.0.2|        63|       2|         1|   0.5|
+---+----+-----------+----------+--------+----------+------+
```